# How do i hit URL using Tcl script?

Tags: url, background, tcl

I am working in Tcl 8.1 and now I am trying to hit an URL using the following command from Tcl Script (which will be called from my application)

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] [list "" $url]
```

But the problem is, it is opening the URL in a web browser. But I don't want the web browser to open as per my requirement. I just want to hit the URL in background.

Is there any solution available to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tcl/Tk 8.1 was realeased in 1999. Good luck with this oldtimer!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly obvious what "hit[ting an] URL in background" means, but I'm guessing that you want to retrieve the contents at an URL and make them available as data in your program.

The `http` module contains the commands you need for this. Basic use:

```
package require http

set token [::http::geturl $url]
puts [::http::data $token]
::http::cleanup $token
```

Documentation: [http](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/http.htm)

P.S. you really need to upgrade, if possible. Even Tcl 8.4 is obsolete nowadays. You will risk having subtle, hard-to-diagnose problems with your programs unless you use a recent version, and a lot of the suggested code for instance here or on the wiki will be unusable to you with a version that old. And Tcl just keeps getting better.

Comment: Thanks @peter, your suggested piece of code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send literal quotes as the first argument for `start`, not an empty string.

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] {""} [list $url]
```

ref: http://wiki.tcl.tk/auto_execok